# Passing Parameters to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

For my current assignment I am suppose to build a website where people can log in, and post comment. I've never done web programming before so I've been struggling through it. right now I am confused as to how I can use the values from text fields on the html web page in the java script I'm using with the page.

this is the code from my Javascript, (it really doesn't do much of anything I'm just trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong)

```
   <script type = "text/javascript">
   function inform(name)
   {
  alert(name);
   }
   </script>
```

and this is  what the html looks like where I call the function

```
<P ALIGN="right">  
        Email: <br><input type="text" name="fname"><br>
        Pass Word: <br><input type="password" name="pass"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Log In" onclick ="inform(document.getElementById('fname').value)"/>
    </P>
```

When I run this and hit the button it says that the value of name in the inform function is always Null regaurdless of what I put in the name text field. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've assigned a `name` instead of an `id`.

```
<!-----------------------------v------------v--->
Email: <br><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
```

---

As an alternative, you could do this:

```
<input type="button" value="Log In" onclick ="inform(this.form.fname.value)"/>
```

---

And in fact, the `this` is even optional:

```
<input type="button" value="Log In" onclick ="inform(form.fname.value)"/>
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/kPcmq/

Comment: Thank you. This is why I love this site, quick and helpful answers

Comment: I can't +1 this because it suggests using [obtrusive JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5871640/1615483). Not to mention a space before the `=` which makes the HTML invalid anyway.

Comment: you're just being nit-picky

Comment: @PaulS.: I'm using the code from the question. In any case, this isn't the place to have an off-topic discussion about philosophies of "obtrusive JavaScript".

Comment: @PaulS.: And it's not invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change this

```
Email: <br><input type="text" name="fname"><br>
```

to `Email: <br><input type="text" name="fname" id ="fname" ><br>`